What 80s or 90s horror movie is set underground with a bunch of soldiers fighting slow moving zombie like monsters
I often have a flicker of a memory which is like a bad itch I have been unable to scratch, scouring the interwebs and all the cult movie lists I can find on IMDB and everywhere else.
There was a movie I watched recorded on VHS many, MANY, years ago and I remember glimpses of it and for some reason I feel like the title had the word "Monsters" in it... I am pretty sure the language of the film was English..
I only recall a few things (which may be entirely incorrect and tarnished by other memories 20 years on) and one scene in particular:

Set in tunnels, or caverns - certainly subterranean.
Male protagonist?
There were a group of soldiers, but possibly mercs? I think there was a female soldier.
The soldiers had automatic weapons/rifles.
The monsters were humanoid in terms of limbs and moved slowly, came out of the ground - they were greyish I think.

The scene I think I recall is when the soldiers made a last stand and the film kept cutting to different shots of tunnels intimating that the creatures were massing and coming to the soldiers - the last man standing ends up being pulled in to the ground/dirt screaming.
I was very young at the time and it was recorded from broadcast TV in Australia - I am going to assume the movie was circa 1990.
In my searches I have found a few titles matching what I have searched (different attempts at describing that which I recall above) but none are it (although in many cases I cannot source a copy of the movie to confirm..)
I hope someone out there might know what movie I am describing! I cannot die without knowing!

It's probably not it, but a few of the plot points you mention (subterranian, army/mercs unit, female soldier etc) match the first Resident Evil film. Any chance that's it?

@Robotnik - you are right, but I know for certain it was a movie from at least 25 years ago.

@tina - I did, GOgreenrangerGO's answer below was the one! I have no clue what film you are after, but I thought of The Secret Garden hehe

Its from a show...Monsters (1988-1990).  The episode was called The Hole (1990)

mate you are a legend!
So I was simply under the impression it was a film that had been taped and not an episode of a TV show!
Your answer has been down voted probably due to the link to YT for a removed vid, but it is the answer!
I found a review vid on YT and the bloke said the standout episode in his memory was this one!
link
THANK YOU!!!!
PS: KAT...

This may be too obvious, but I'll throw it out so you can judge for yourself.
Possibly Day of the Dead (1985)? The third in George A. Romero's zombie series.

A small group of military officers and scientists dwell in an
  underground bunker as the world above is overrun by zombies.

imdb
Underground, soldiers, automatic weapons but no female soldier that I can recall.
You can find the whole film on youtube (I'm not sure of the legality, so I won't post a link).

thank you for your response - I cannot believe I have overlooked that film all this time - however I just do not think that Day of the Dead (1985) is it; it is exactly what I described, but I found no scene matching my memories - specifically the "monsters" coming through dirt walls and up out of the ground to overwhelm the last man standing.
Further recollection has me remember why I think the word "monsters" is in the title - there were commercials recorded as well and the movie title is displayed upon return.
I will just have to accept the fact I may never know what it was that I watched.

What is the correct etiquette in this case? do I mark your Answer as the answer or just leave it at that for the mods to close?
I tried marking your answer as useful but not enough rep sorry.

@metcaelfe - No need to do anything with this one. Just wait for the next answer (which may be the film that you are looking for).

I thought of this at first, but the description of a "last man standing" and monsters coming out of the ground didn't jibe.
